# error building the first program from Hillegass's book: Cocoa Programming for Mac OS X

Tags: objective-c, interface-builder

I'm trying to build the first program in Aaron Hillegass's  book: *Cocoa(R) Programming for Mac(R) OS X (3rd Edition)*. The problem I'm having is that I can't my Interface object to "spawn" for lack of a better term unless I build and run the program. Herein lies the problem. While the program is running I can't connect the code to the interface. I'm coding in objective - c on a mac

Comment: You know that a title should be short and descriptive?

Comment: Please give your question a shorter, more meaningful title. Furthermore you may want to provide some error messages to us, or some code you have written. If I tell you my car is not working and I have winter tires, what would you suggest?

Comment: And why is your actual question in a blockquote?

Answer (score 2):

I have followed step by step exactly what Hillegass wrote in his book and the program just ran fine.

Looks like you forgot something, but without more precision nobody can tell you what.